# "! Incomplete \ifnum" Error using acronym in combination with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, acronyms

I am experiencing an error using the acronym package in combination with hyperref. The error Message is:

`! Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line 83.`

MWE below, i have no idea what is happening.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, withpage, smaller]{acronym}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
  pdftitle = {pdftitle},
  pdfauthor = {author}
  hidelinks,
  unicode,
  bookmarksopenlevel=Section,
  colorlinks=false,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,
  linktoc=all,pdfa,
  bookmarks=true
}

\clubpenalty1000000
\widowpenalty1000000
\displaywidowpenalty1000000


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{AF}[AF]{Access Flow, Shuntfluss}
  \acro{AR}[AR]{Access Recirculation, Suntrezirkulation}
  \acro{AV}[AV]{Arteriovenöse}
  \acro{BVM}[BVM]{Blutvolumenmodul}
\end{acronym}

\ac{BVM}

\section{two}

\lipsum[2] \ac{AV}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fix is here ... https://github.com/oetiker/acronym/pull/19 there is unfortunately another issue causing compile to fail the first time if there is no .aux file ... so that needs to be fixed too before I can release a new version.

```
diff --git a/acronym.dtx b/acronym.dtx
index 2e0378e..fc5013c 100644
--- a/acronym.dtx
+++ b/acronym.dtx
@@ -1254,14 +1254,14 @@ blocks to be tested separately. The latter are commonly indicated as
     \ifAC@printonlyused 1%
     \else\ifAC@printonlyreused 1%
     \else 0\fi\fi%
-  =1%
+  =1\relax%
     \ifnum%
       \ifAC@printonlyused%
         \expandafter\ifx\csname acused@#1@once\endcsname\AC@used 1 \else 0 \fi%
       \else\ifAC@printonlyreused%
         \expandafter\ifx\csname acused@#1@twice\endcsname\AC@used 1 \else 0 \fi%
       \else 0 \fi\fi%
-    =1%
+    =1\relax%
       \item[\protect\AC@hypertarget{#1}{%
         \AC@hyperref[acro:#1]{\aclabelfont{#2}\hfill}%
       }]\AC@hyperref[acro:#1]{#3}%
```